# How do I set the title of Terminal.app with the fish shell?

Tags: macos, mac, terminal.app, fish

I'm trying the [fish shell](http://fishshell.org/) in Mac OS X, intalled using MacPorts. I'd like to have the title of my Terminal window be my current directory. Currently, the title just says

```
Terminal - fish - 80x24
```

According to the fish documentation, the default `fish_title` function should provide this behavior. It doesn't do the right thing in Terminal.app, although it does work with [iTerm](http://iterm.sourceforge.net/). Defining my own fish_title function doesn't fix the problem.

Has anybody been able to get this to work?

Comment: Please post your code that sets fish_title.

Comment: This will set the window title in bash and zsh: `printf '\e]2;Custom Window Title\a'`  Does that work in fish?

Comment: For comparison, try doing it using fish in xterm and see if it works there. Another thing to check is the value of $TERM. In Lion, Terminal changed the default value from "xterm-color" to "xterm-256color". Perhaps fish is depending on $TERM to decide whether to actually emit the escape sequence to set the title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I installed fish (1.23.1) to investigate this. It turns out that fish only updates the title if `$TERM` is one of the following: `xterm`, `screen`, `nxterm`, `rxvt`. Otherwise, it never calls the `fish_title` function.

Terminal's default value is `xterm-256color` and prior to Mac OS X Lion 10.7 it was `xterm-color`, neither of which is recognized by fish. Fish is simply being unreasonably conservative about which terminfo values it thinks support this feature. `fish_title` isn't called for any `xterm*` variants, for example.

To work around this limitation of fish, you can set `$TERM` to `xterm`. The simplest way to do this is with a Terminal preference setting:

> Terminal > Preferences > Settings > [profile] > Advanced > Declare terminal as

Select `xterm` from the popup menu. This preference controls the value of `$TERM` (that's all it does).

Note that using `xterm` instead of Terminal's default may disable some terminal functionality or, prior to Lion, cause misbehavior due to incompatibilities between the `xterm` terminfo description and older versions of Terminal.

Therefore, if fish isn't your default shell, you may want to only change `$TERM` when invoking fish. e.g., you can invoke fish with `TERM=xterm fish` from a shell, or you can create a custom Terminal settings profile just for running fish (you can set the "Run command" preference to invoke fish, so creating a new terminal window or tab with this profile will automatically run fish).

Or, if you're not shy about modifying fish: once you've installed it via MacPorts or Fink you've got the sources sitting on your machine and you can extend its list of recognized $TERM values, or even update the code to allow for suffixes on the recognized values. e.g., it should at least allow any values that start with `xterm` or `screen`. Otherwise, it's not even going to work with common `screen` variants. And if you do that, please contribute it back to the fish project.

Answer (score 10):

If you found this question wondering how to change the window/tab title in fish, and the `fish_title` function works for you (see [Chris Page's answer](https://superuser.com/a/329277/12724)), then here's an example that sets the title to use a shortened version of your working directory.

```
$ funced fish_title

function fish_title
    if [ $_ = 'fish' ]
        echo (prompt_pwd)
    else
        echo $_
    end
end

$ funcsave fish_title
```

Answer (score -1):

It is likely something to do with the configuration of `Terminal.app`. I'm running Terminal 2.0.2 on Leopard which allows me to configure the window's title via the preferences (see settings -> window).

It's possible that enabling 'shell command name' might get your desired result. The default is just to display `Terminal - $process - $size` probably over-rules the fish environment.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. For example, in bash, one can set the title following these instructions: http://superuser.com/questions/79972/set-the-title-of-the-terminal-window-to-the-current-directory. But those instructions don't work for the fish shell.

Comment: None of Terminal's preferences will override or disable the escape sequence for setting the window and tab titles.