# Window Title in Bash

Tags: bash

How can I set the window title in Bash?  I do know that in Windows Batch it is TITLE.

Comment: => superuser.com

Comment: it's kind of programming related, sorta...

Comment: Similiar to this question?

http://superuser.com/questions/79972/set-the-title-of-the-terminal-window-to-the-current-directory

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here is a nice function to do it:

```
# Allow the user to set the title.
function title {
   PROMPT_COMMAND="echo -ne \"\033]0;$1 (on $HOSTNAME)\007\""
}
```

Put that in your ~/.bashrc, then type "title whatever" to set the title.  If you want to get rid of the hostname, remove "(on $HOSTNAME)".

Edit: make sure to `. ~/.bashrc` (aka `source ~/.bashrc`) before trying, of course.

[Source link.](http://www.kirsle.net/blog.html?u=kirsle&id=52)

Comment: How can i just do everything in the code? I dont want the user to type it in.

Comment: You could have your bash code call the title function.

Comment: it does not work, when i enter the function stuff, and then enter this `title Hey!`, it does not work. What to do?

Comment: At the risk of repeating myself, did you remember to execute your bashrc script after editing it?  It works fine for me.

Comment: @YourComputerHelpZ: are you using an xterm, or another kind of console such as Konsole or yakuake ?

Comment: i am using gnome

Comment: Different reference/source link: [xterm Title Bar Manipulations, in Bash Prompt HOWTO](http://www.iitk.ac.in/LDP/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/xterm-title-bar-manipulations.html)

Comment: run `echo -ne \"\033]0;$1 (on $HOSTNAME)\007\"` directly also change title on running

Answer (score 3):

I have this VT100 escape sequence defined in `.bashrc`.

```
PS1_SET_TITLE='\[\e]0;\u@\h:\w\a\]'

PS1="${PS1_SET_TITLE}" my other prompt components

export PS1
```

For my home directory it displays `alex@host:~`, when I change directories, they are updated in window title.

Works with CYGWIN and PuTTY terminal sessions. I usually don't run X, but when I did it worked fine with XTerm.

Read `PROMPTING` section of bash man page on available switches for PS commands, e.g `\u \h \w`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some code to set window title in *bash* - an improved version, that doesn't remove
previous prompt string (and changes to it are temporary), of another answer (quoted below):

```
function title {
    export WTITLE=$1
}
PS1_old="$(echo $PS1 | sed -En 's/(.+)\\e](.+)/\1\\\\e]\2/g; s/(.+ )(.+)/\1\\n\2/p')";
_PS1='\[\e]0;$WTITLE: \w\a\]';_PS1+="$PS1_old ";export PS1=$_PS1;

# A command to use in bash (shell) scripts, replaces
# the above function that is for a "~/.bashrc" file:
export WTITLE="[for example \u@\h, insert title here]"
```

> If you are using "mintty" (the default terminal of Cygwin since end 2011),
>   add the following in `.bashrc` :
>
> ```
> function title {
>     export WINDOWTITLE=$1
> }    
> export PS1='\[\e]0;$WINDOWTITLE:\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]~\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$'
> ```
>
> and reopen your terminal and type "title ThisIsMyTitle"

*- quote from [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/84710/window-title-in-bash/472367#472367).*

Answer (score 2):

Wrote a function title. It supports echo-like escape sequences and `-e` + `-E`.

```
title () {
  echo -ne "\e]0;"
  echo -n "$@"
  echo -ne "\a"
}
```

I put it in my `.bash` folder and sourced it from `.bash/global.rc`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using "mintty" (the default terminal of Cygwin since end 2011), add the following in `.bashrc` :

```
function title {
   export WINDOWTITLE=$1
}    
export PS1='\[\e]0;$WINDOWTITLE:\w\a\]\n\[\e[32m\]\u@\h \[\e[33m\]~\w\[\e[0m\]\n\$'
```

and reopen your terminal and type "title ThisIsMyTitle"

Comment: There's an improved version of this, that doesn't remove (previous) prompt string, at https://superuser.com/a/1366261/736409 .

Answer (score 0):

**We need more information:** The answer will depend on what terminal you're using, not what shell.  Is this in an xterm?  An rxvt?  A cygwin window on windows?  Etc.

(danben's answer works for xterms, and probably for rxvt terminals)

Comment: i use Terminal on Linux Mint

Answer (score 0):

I use simple `title` bash script that lies in `PATH`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo -ne "\033]0;$@\007"
```

Usage:

```
title My favourite window title
```

Works once, so if any other program changes the title - you need to run the script once again.